# How to invoke setter method when using methods with arguments in UIInput components?

Tags: java, jsf-2, el, mojarra

Before I have used methods with arguments to obtain the values of a component on my JSF page, for example

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.getMyList(argument)}">
```

However now I need the same principle, but using it on a value attribute of an inputText element, so it would be more or less like this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.getMyValue(argment)}">
```

The problem is that the second method will not invoke the setter method, when executing the element from a f:ajax element.

What would be another way of passing values to the setter and getter methods on the backingBean?.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's indeed not possible to set a value on an EL expression which does not represent a getter. You'd need to turn `myValue` into a `Map<String, Object>` and use the following notation.

```html
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.myValue[argument]}">
```

This will then call the `put()` method on the `Map`. Note that you don't need a setter for `myValue` here.